# Calling exit() in C++ library terminates python script that wrapps that library using swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm writing a Swig-Python wrapper for a C++ library. When critical error occurs, the library calls `exit(err);`, which in turn terminates the whole python script that executes functions from that library.

Is there a way to wrap around `exit()` function to return to the script or throw an exception?

Comment: This might help you: [Override a function call in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c)

Comment: Calling `exit()` from a library when you have exceptions available shows that the author is probably clueless concerning error handling. Consider fixing that library or replacing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can put together a massive hack for this using `longjmp` and `on_exit`, although I highly recommend avoiding this in favour of a solution with multiple processes, which I'll outline later in the answer.

Suppose we have the following (broken by design) header file:

```c
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <stdlib.h>

inline void fail_test(int fail) {
  if (fail) exit(fail);
}

#endif//TEST_H
```

We want to wrap it and convert the call to `exit()` into a Python exception instead. One way to achieve this would be something like the following interface, which uses `%exception` to insert C code around the call to every C function from your Python interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <setjmp.h>

static __thread int infunc = 0;
static __thread jmp_buf buf;

static void exithack(int code, void *data) {
  if (!infunc) return;
  (void)data;
  longjmp(buf,code);
}
%}

%init %{
  on_exit(exithack, NULL);
%}

%exception {
  infunc = 1;
  int err = 0;
  if (!(err=setjmp(buf))) {
    $action
  }
  else {
    // Raise exception, code=err
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_Exception, "%d", err);
    infunc = 0;
    on_exit(exithack, NULL);
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  infunc = 0;
}

%include "test.h"
```

This "works" when we compile it:

```
swig3.0 -python -py3 -Wall test.i
gcc -shared test_wrap.c -o _test.so -I/usr/include/python3.4 -Wall -Wextra -lpython3.4m
```

And we can demonstrate it with:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:14:40)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.fail_test(0)
>>> test.fail_test(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: 123
>>> test.fail_test(0)
>>> test.fail_test(999)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: 999
>>>
```

It's very ugly though, almost certainly not portable and most likely undefined behaviour as well.

---

My advice would be not to do that and use a solution with two processes communicating instead. We can still have SWIG help us generate a nice module and better yet we can rely on some high-level Python constructs to help us with that. The complete example looks like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"

static void exit_handler(int code, void *fd) {
  FILE *f = fdopen((int)fd, "w");
  fprintf(stderr, "In exit handler: %d\n", code);
  fprintf(f, "(dp0\nVexited\np1\nL%dL\ns.", code);
  fclose(f);
}
%}

%typemap(in) int fd %{
  $1 = PyObject_AsFileDescriptor($input);
%}

%inline %{
  void enter_work_loop(int fd) {
    on_exit(exit_handler, (void*)fd);
  }
%}

%pythoncode %{
import os
import pickle

serialize=pickle.dump
deserialize=pickle.load

def do_work(wrapped, args_pipe, results_pipe):
  wrapped.enter_work_loop(results_pipe)

  while True:
    try:
      args = deserialize(args_pipe)
      f = getattr(wrapped, args['name'])
      result = f(*args['args'], **args['kwargs'])
      serialize({'value':result},results_pipe)
      results_pipe.flush()
    except Exception as e:
      serialize({'exception': e},results_pipe)
      results_pipe.flush()

class ProxyModule():
  def __init__(self, wrapped):
    self.wrapped = wrapped
    self.prefix = "_worker_"

  def __dir__(self):
    return [x.strip(self.prefix) for x in dir(self.wrapped) if x.startswith(self.prefix)]

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    def proxy_call(*args, **kwargs):
      serialize({
        'name': '%s%s' % (self.prefix, name),
        'args': args,
        'kwargs': kwargs
      }, self.args[1])
      self.args[1].flush()
      result = deserialize(self.results[0])
      if 'exception' in result: raise result['exception']
      if 'exited' in result: raise Exception('Library exited with code: %d' % result['exited'])
      return result['value']
    return proxy_call

  def init_library(self):
    def pipes():
      r,w=os.pipe()
      return os.fdopen(r,'rb',0), os.fdopen(w,'wb',0)

    self.args = pipes()
    self.results = pipes()

    self.worker = os.fork()

    if 0==self.worker:
      do_work(self.wrapped, self.args[0], self.results[1])
%}

// rename all our wrapped functions to be _worker_FUNCNAME to hide them - we'll call them from within the other process
%rename("_worker_%s") "";
%include "test.h"

%pythoncode %{
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = ProxyModule(sys.modules[__name__])
%}
```

Which uses the following ideas:

1. [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) to serialise data before writing it over pipes to a worker process.
2. [`os.fork`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538466/regarding-the-os-fork-function-in-python) to spawn the worker process, with `os.fdopen` creating a nicer object for use in Python
3. [SWIG's advanced renaming](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) to hide the actual functions we wrapped from users of the module, but still wrap them
4. A trick to [replace the module with a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module) that implements `__getattr__` to return proxy functions for the worker process
5. [`__dir__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870241/ipython-tab-completion-for-custom-dict-class) to keep <kbd>TAB</kbd> working inside ipython
6. `on_exit` to intercept the exit (but not divert it) and report the code back via a pre-written ASCII pickled object

You could make the call to `library_init` transparent and automatic if you wished so. You also need to handle the case where the worker hasn't been started or has already exited better (it'll just block in my example). And you'll also need to ensure that the worker gets cleaned up at exit properly, but it now lets you run:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:14:40)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.init_library()
>>> test.fail_test(2)
In exit handler: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/lislan/ajw/code/scratch/swig/pyatexit/test.py", line 117, in proxy_call
    if 'exited' in result: raise Exception('Library exited with code: %d' % result['exited'])
Exception: Library exited with code: 2
>>>
```

and still be (somewhat) portable, but definitely well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's difficult to offer a solution, however:

Did you write the library? If so can you rework it to throw a `logic_error` instead of calling `exit`?

If the library is calling `exit`, this implies an utterly catastrophic failure. The internal state of the library could well be inconsistent (you ought to assume that it is!) - are you sure you want to continue the process after this? If you didn't write the library you're not in a position to reason about this. If you did, see above.

Perhaps you could write a wrapper process around the library, and marshall calls across the process boundary? This will be slower in execution and more painful to write and maintain, but it will allow the parent process (python) to detect the termination of the child (the library wrapper).

Comment: I don't have control over the library. In my python script I want to know that something wrong happened to the function I called and act accordingly, therefore I want to be able to "catch" exits. I think of overriding`exit()` with `my_exit()` that will through exception that would be cached by the python script.

Comment: right, but if you do that you should take care not to call anything else in the library since it will be inconsistent. The only reasonable action to take after this is to inform the user and exit the process.

Comment: I think your best bet is to fork your python process, do the work in the child. The parent can wait for the child to complete. Then you're safe.