# How to enable specific tab-completion of functions for instances of a custom class in IPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, jupyter-notebook, magic-methods

I'm creating a customized class that inherits `dict` with `__init__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, and `update` as functions of this custom class. When creating an instance of the the class in a jupyter notebook, I would like to tab-complete when dot accessing attributes of this instance:

```py
some_instance = Foo()
some_instance. # pressing tab should only show 'update'
```

and `dir()` would print

```py
dir(some_instance)

# output: ['update']
```

The official docs weren't too helpful beyond explaining simply what `__dir__` does, and [ipython tab completion for custom dict class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870241/ipython-tab-completion-for-custom-dict-class) didn't help me with this too much.

I'm not really sure how this works or what it's doing, but adding following function to the class does exactly what I want:

```py
def __dir__(self):
    return ['update']
```

Here's what I have so far:

```py
# this file is located in some_lib

import json

def save(obj, name):
    with open(name, 'w+') as file_:
        json.dump(obj, file_)

def load(name):
    with open(name, 'r') as file_:
        return json.load(file_)

class BijectiveDict(dict):
    """
    References
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map
    """
    def __init__(self, dict_={}):
        assert isinstance(dict_, dict), "Argument Error: dict_ is not of type dict"

        for key, val in dict_.items():
            self.update(key, val)

    def __setitem__(self, x, y):
        # override how self[key] = value works since this class inherits Dict.
        # this way, self.add can work as expected

        # delete any old pairs that contain x or y
        if x in self:
            del self[x]
        if y in self:
            del self[y]

        dict.__setitem__(self, x, y)
        dict.__setitem__(self, y, x)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, self[key])
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)

    def __len__(self):
        # returns number of unique mappings
        return dict.__len__(self) // 2

    def __dir__(self):
        return ["update"]

    def update(self, x, y):
        self[x] = y
```

If I have

```py
import some_lib
some_map = some_lib.BijectiveDict()
some_map. # using dot access and pressing tab returns methods from the dict class
```

then dot accessing has the following tab-completions (if `__dir__` is not defined):

```
['clear',
 'copy',
 'fromkeys',
 'get',
 'items',
 'keys',
 'pop',
 'popitem',
 'setdefault',
 'test_name',
 'update',
 'values']
```

Is defining `__dir__` as such the only way? If my class will have a bunch of methods and I forget to include that in the list returned by dir, what do I do then? Is there an automatic way?

On a similar note, why does tab-completing some_lib shows `json, save, load`?
Do I also have to define another `__dir__`?